# Getting Doxygen and MSVC TODO tags to work together

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, doxygen, todo

In doxygen, the standard "/// \todo stuff" is used to tag a todo item.  I do most of my coding in MSVC so it's handy to be able to see the TODO's in the Task List.  MSVC uses "//TODO stuff" for their tags.  Is there any way to make them work together?  I found the properties pane for the Task list and try to add "\todo" to the list, but it doesn't like the "\" character.  Can I make these two work together?

Edit:  I am specifically interested to find out how to do this in Visual Studio 10.

Answer (score 9):

IIRC doxygen **supports javadoc-style** structural commands, i.e. you should be able to [use `@todo` and `\todo` interchangeably](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands), in the eventuality that MSVC *will* accept `@todo` as a task marker:

> Structural commands (like all other
>   commands) start with a backslash (),
>   or an at-sign (@) if you prefer
>   JavaDoc style, followed by a command
>   name and one or more parameters.

**Another option** is to use [`FILE_VERSION_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_file_version_filter) as a doxygen preprocessor, providing a custom script (or program), e.g. if you have Cygwin installed in `C:\cygwin` then the following will work nicely:

```
FILE_VERSION_FILTER = "C:\cygwin\bin\sed -e 's:// *TODO:@todo:g'"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MSVC 2010 says that the only valid characters for a task list token are the alphanumeric characters, _, $, and parentheses.  A pre-processing step for doxygen seems to be the only option...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the way VS treats these "TODO"s. But I think there is an easy way if it also recognizes \TODO as a to do item. In this case you might want to have a look at the [doxygen documentation for \xref](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem). This allows you to create tag/commands and link to a special section and a related page. \todo or @todo is defined as

```
\xrefitem todo "Todo" "Todo List"
```

What you can do now to create a custom "\TODO" or "@TODO" command is go to your configuration file or the doxywizard and add the line

```
\xrefitem TODO "Todo" "Todo List"
```

to it. Maybe that helps.