# Expand macro inside doxygen comment for printing out software version

Tags: c++, makefile, doxygen

I have some C++ code base, documented with doxygen, and build with GNU make.
Version information is centralized in makefile, where I have something like:

> VERSION=1.2.3.4

In my makefile, the CFLAGS add the following define:

> CFLAGS += -DAPP_VERSION=$(VERSION)

This enables me to get the version in code, like this:

```
#define STR_EXPAND(tok) #tok
#define STR(tok) STR_EXPAND(tok)
int main()
{
    cout << "software version is << STR(APP_VERSION) << endl;
}
```

Now, what I would like is to have this in the doxygen-produced html files:

> Current version of software is 1.2.3.4

I managed to export the makefile variable into the doxygen configuration file with:
(**edit**: doxygen is called from makefile, through a 'make-doc' target)

> PREDEFINED = APP_VERSION=$(VERSION)

But then, if I try in the doxygen \mainpage command something like this, it fails, because (of course), macro names don't get expanded in comments...

```
/**
\mainpage this is the doc
Current version is $(APP_VERSION) -- or -- ... is APP_VERSION
*/
```

**Questions**

- Do you know of a way to "expand" that macro in the doxygen comments ? This could be done by some sed processing on the file holding the comment in the makefile, but maybe this can be solved directly with doxygen ?
- How do other projects handle versioning (besides automatic versioning tool that VCS provide, I mean), in a way that the version id is uniquely defined in a file, so it can be fetched both by software build system and documentation build system.

Related: [How to display a defined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137566/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "export" functionality of make ie a very simple make file with

```
project_name=FooBar
export project_name
all:
    doxygen Doxyfile
```

Will allow you to use the following comments in C++

```
/*! \mainpage Project $(project_name) Lorem ipsum dolor
```

I can see this becoming a PITA with a large set of exports but it's a fairly simple way to do it. Alternatively you could run doxygen from a separate BASH script with all the exports in it to avoid polluting your Makefile too much.

Comment: I just come back to this question and realize (with some delay...) that this is exactly what I was looking for! I don't way I didnt spot it at that time. Accepting answer.

Answer (score 3):

Macros in comments are not generally expanded (see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9299914/623518)). This is not unique to doxygen and I can 't think of a way to do this using the `PREDEFINED` configuration option.

As you state in the question, you can use `sed`, see the third bullet point in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8726335/623518). For example, using the following

```
INPUT_FILTER  = "sed -e 's/VERSION/1.0/'"
```

will replace all instances of `VERSION` with `1.0` in all your source files (you can specify which files to process with [`INPUT_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter), rather than processing all source files). You might not want `VERSION` to be expanded everywhere, so perhaps it is best to use something like `$(VERSION)` and `sed` this token. Also, you will need a way of getting your version number from your makefile and into your doxygen configuration file. This can be done with another `sed`.

To address your last bullet point, doxygen has the [`FILE_VERSION_FILTER`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_file_version_filter) configuration option for determining the version number of each file. Using this will print some version information (whatever is printed to standard out from the command specified in `FILE_VERSION_FILTER`) at the top of each file page. In the documentation there are examples of getting the version number using a number of different version control systems. Also, [here](http://alip.github.com//en/blog/2010/12/14/doxygen-git/) is a page describing how to use git and doxygen to extract version information.

The only drawback with this configuration option is that I don't know how to specify where the file version information should appear in the final documentation. I presume you can use a layout file: I presume you can [change the layout of pages](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout), but I have never done this and don't know how easy it would be to use this to include version information on the mainpage.

Comment: Actually, the version number is also uniquely located in the doxygen comments, so what I had in mind was more to 'sed' directly the source/header file where it is located. But the idea of processing automatically all files through the provided doxygen mechanism is a good idea too.
And for getting the version number from the makefile into the doxygen configuration file, this is done with:
PREDEFINED = APP_VERSION=$(VERSION)

Answer (score 2):

the [commands manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html) suggests that `$(VARIABLE)` expands environment variables. So maybe you can put your version in an environment variable?

Comment: Sure, but the point is: how do I get its value printed out in doxygen generated files? Or maybe I misunderstood your answer, could you clarify?

Comment: Worked for me with Doxygen 1.8.6 on Windows.
 
In batch file:

    set DOC_VERSION=1.0

In MyPage.dox:

    Version: $(DOC_VERSION)