# How to insert the project name in a comment in doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I often use the project name in comments I write. However, up until now I hardcoded it. Now I realized that if the project name were to change, I would have to go through all the documentation parts and change it. Therefore, I wanted to ask if it is possible to simply reference the project name in the comment and let doxygen fill it out later.

```
/*! \brief This is the main function of the (project_name) project
*/
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at ALIASES to define your own command using an environment variable or fixed name to use in the comment.

Comment: I tried this already, but it does not seem to work (see comments below MattOnyx answer)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is environment variables, which you can read about [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html).
The one you are looking for should be `$(PROJECT_NAME)`.
To use it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692970/expand-macro-inside-doxygen-comment-for-printing-out-software-version/14081363#14081363).

Comment: If I insert it in a comment block, `$(PROJECT_NAME)` is ignored.

Comment: I also tried via an alias: `projectName=$(PROJECT_NAME)`. But this also has no effect. If I try instead: `projectName=test`, the alias command works. So maybe the `PROJECT_NAME` env. var. is not resolved at the correct time?

Comment: Did you set `PROJECT_NAME = "MY PROJECT NAME"` your doxygen config file ?

Comment: Yes. Or more precisely, the doxygen-wizard did for me. Otherwise it would also not show in the generated html I guess, if this was broken.

Comment: I would not refer to a very old manual but to the official doxygen site: http://www.doxygen.org where the current manual can be found and the current chapter http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14081363/3617473), it could help.

Comment: Hm. I would prefer a solution where you can use the project name that is already in the doxygen configuration file instead of defining it outside.

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is from ages ago, and you've probably found an answer or moved on. But fwiw, I had a similar need and didn't find a direct answer here or at other similar Stack Overflow questions, so I'll offer what worked for me:

**In my Doxygen comment block, the command `\doxyconfig <config_option>` is what did the trick.**

E.g., my *Doxyfile*:

```
PROJECT_NAME = hello-world
PROJECT_NUMBER = 0.1.0

INPUT = "C:/dev/hello-world/src" 
INPUT += "C:/dev/hello-world/doc/mainpage.txt"

OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "C:/dev/hello-world/doc"

OUTPUT_LANGUAGE = English

FILE_PATTERNS = *.c *.h
RECURSIVE = YES
```

...and my *mainpage.txt*, which you'll note is referenced as an `INPUT` value in the *Doxyfile* above:

```
/**
 * @mainpage Main page
 * This page is for project @doxyconfig PROJECT_NAME
 */
```

The resulting output in the HTML landing page:

> This page is for project hello-world

Comment: Correct, the `\doxyconfig` command was introduced in doxygen version 1.9.7 (May 18, 2023). (Note: The current doxygen version is 1.10.0)