# Doxygen: Outputting Version Numbers

Tags: versioning, doxygen

I would like to have Doxygen display the source code version number as part of the main page or the title header.

Presently, our code has the version defined as a text literal:

```
/*!
 *  \brief  Text literal containing the build number portion of the
 *              ESG Application Version.
 */
static const char   build_version_text[] = "105";
```

I have searched the internet for a method to get the 105 from the above statement into the Doxygen main page (or header) with no luck.

*Background*
We have a build server that updates the text string as part of a nightly build operation.  The file is updated, then checked into the Software Configuration Management system.  The build server is also capable of generating the documentation.  We would also like to have the developers be able to check out the code, the build the Doxygen documentation at their workstations.

We are using Doxygen version 1.8.11.

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692970/

Comment: I read that, but I was hoping for a solution that doesn't involve environment variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, please check my revised answer. There are no environment variables, the script is driven by doxygen itself, so should be ok to use both in the automated build and by a developer at his/her workstation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is to set the `PROJECT_NUMBER` config option based on the value in your source. I don't think this can be done, but the way I would go about achieving the same result is as follows.

Since the project version is updated when a build script runs, have the build script generate an extra file, for example `Doxyversion`. Have the content of the file be:

```
PROJECT_NUMBER = "<versiontext>"
```

Update your main Doxyfile and replace

```
PROJECT_NUMBER =
```

with

```
@INCLUDE = "<pathToDoxyversion>"
```

Edit:

A solution I can think of that does not require duplicating the version string requires parsing the version string out from the file into an environment variable. Then you can set `PROJECT_NUMBER` to

```
PROJECT_NUMBER=$(ENV_VAR)
```

Another option is you can call doxygen with

```
( cat Doxyfile ; echo "PROJECT_NUMBER=$ENV_VAR" ) | doxygen
```

Both solutions would require the developers to know to do this when generating the documentation, or wrapping the entire doxygen call in a script. Also potential portability issues.

Comment: I don't see the need for the extra file.  We can write a build script that can insert (replace) text for the PROJECT_NUMBER option.  I'm hoping for a solution with only one instance of the version string.

Comment: Fair Enough, I added a way I can think of accomplishing that, but I find it to be worse than the duplicate value heh.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution below, from a real example.

### Main page

In the documentation for the main page (or anywhere, really), use special markers for the text to substitute dynamically.

Main page source:
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/mysqld.cc#L22

See the special `${DOXYGEN_GENERATION_DATE}` markers

### Doxygen input filters

In the doxygen configuration file, define an input filter for the file containing the special markers. For example,

```
FILTER_PATTERNS = "*/sql/mysqld.cc=./doxygen-filter-mysqld"
```

Implement the `doxygen-filter-mysqld` script to:

- Find the dynamic value to substitute (in your case, parse the value of `build_version_text`)
- Replace (`sed`) the special marker with the value
- Output the result to `stdout`

For example:

```
CMD1="s/\\\${DOXYGEN_GENERATION_DATE}/"`date -I`"/g"
...
sed -e ${CMD1} -e ${CMD2} -e ${CMD3} $1
```

### Results

Result is at
http://devdocs.no.oracle.com/mysql-server/8.0.0/

### See Also

All this is a work around for that I think should be a good Doxygen feature.
See bug#769679 (Feature Request: doxygen command to expand an environment variable) that was entered for this.

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769679